# How to write join query using hibernate criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to hibernate criteria API. I have written the below query in SQL. How to write it in the Hibernate criteria?

```
select * from Employee ju, Address ua where
ua.loginname=ju.loginname
and ua.countryname='USA'
and ju.siteprimcontact=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on the JPA Criteria API that you can use to learn how to write such queries: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html